# C# File Last Modified time

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the last write time of a particular file. This is the code and it works:`

```
DirectoryInfo DR = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);  
FileInfo[] FR2 = DR.GetFiles("InputData.csv");
var FileLastModified= null;

foreach (FileInfo F1 in FR2)
{
    FileLastModified = F1.LastWriteTime;
}
```

FileLastModified gives me the last write time and I am only interested to find the time of this InputData.csv file. The problem is I do not want to use a for loop and need the write time for just one particular file. Is there a better way to write this without the loop?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't work - it doesn't compile. You can't declare a variable using `var` and initialize it with a value of `null`.

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to search through a directory to get a `FileInfo` - [you can construct one directly from the full path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo). It sounds like you just need:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(folderPath, "InputData.csv"));
var lastModified = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can just pass the path to the file you're interested in to a `new FileInfo` object.

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(pathToFile);
var fileLastModified = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
```

Comment: thank you sir. I had to use the combine path as mentioned in the post above because there were a lot of files in that path.